# .htaccess file not allowing access to subdirectories

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am having trouble with my .htaccess file. For the most part, it works OK. However, I am having trouble accessing a subdirectory's index via the folder name (for example www.website.com/blog/).

The content of my .htaccess file is included here:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.com/profile.php?u=$1 [NC]
```

I would like to make it so that I can access a subdirectory via just the directory name with a slash (www.website.com/blog/). Anyone know whats going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Did u enable rewrite module in apache?

Comment: I am not sure if its enabled, but I am using a shared hosting account and the redirects work. for example, www.website.com/blog/index.php works perfectly well. However, if I leave index.php off of the end, then the .htaccess file is directing me to profile.php (as in my example code). I want it to ignore cases where there is nothing after the trailing slash.